# algorithm: random distribution with constraint max-min<=diff

Tags: algorithm

I want to  put `n balls` into `m buckets` **at random**, with constraint that

```
ballCountMax-ballCountMin <= diff
ballCountMax-ballCountMin as random as possible
```

and

```
Input: 
  ballCount: n
  bucketCount: m 
  allowedDiff: diff

Output: 
  ballCount distribution for buckets
```

Is there a good algorithm?

Comment: how strict is that constraint? That is, if you built a probability distribution that was based on that constraint, it's still possible to generate a set that may be slightly outside it

Comment: Are the balls distinguishable? or are they all the same?

Comment: @jozefg, they are all the same, only ball count matters

Comment: What does "at random" mean with respect to probability distributions? If it means "each ball has equal probability of being placed in each bucket", then the constraint makes that impossible. Are you asking for a probability distribution (that would be a function of the current state of the buckets) that satisfies the constraint, or are you asking for an algorithm that uses an equal probability distribution at the core to generate a distribution that satisfies the constraint?

Comment: If it's strict, just run a uniform distribution random number generator through m, and any time a bucket difference reaches diff, put the next one in min

Comment: but that violates randomness to a degree

Comment: but that seems like an impossible conflict to me (random + constraint). If you have a constraint and desire uniform distribution, I think that's "as random" as you will get.

Answer (score 3):

To distribute the balls, simply go down the line, asking for a random number [0, 1) if it's less than 1/(total buckets remaining) place a ball in the bin and move on to the next bin. If at the end of this, you still have balls remaining, evaluate the differences between the bins, if bins are as far apart as allowed ignore bins which are at the maximum for this pass. Do this by finding the minimum and ignoring any balls more than the `minimum+difference-1` Repeat this process until you have distributed all your balls.

The complexity of this algorithm is dependent on the number of balls (n) and the number of buckets (m). It has a complexity of `O(mn)`.

We can speed this up significantly by realizing that each bucket must contain a certain minimum number of balls, for example with 5 buckets and 10 balls with a difference of 2 each bucket must have at least 1 ball. Therefore before even executing the main algorithm we can save half the running time by "pre-placing" the balls into each bucket.

To calculate the number of pre-placeable balls we simply must divide number of balls by number of buckets `n/m` and take the floor and ceiling of this so that `a = ceiling(n/m)` and `b = floor(n/m)`

Now `b` should be the minimum number of balls possible for each bucket iff `a-b = diff`. There are numerous ways to solve this if the equation isn't initially true, such as

```
while(a-b<diff){
  ++a;
  --b;
}
```

Note that in all cases this method will return incorrect results, therefore adding a check that `a-b = diff` is necessary.

We can therefore pre-place `b` balls.

Comment: Yeah, hang on I thought of an optimization

Comment: ha, your optimization is a bit like the idea I just thought

Comment: @smilingpoplar The problem is that you can't guarantee that all your numbers are less than n

Comment: @smilingpoplar plus if n/m isn't even you have to do weird things with floors and ceilings

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18244/discussion-between-jozefg-and-smilingpoplar)

Comment: I came out a better idea. Wait, I am posting it.

Comment: check out my last past, any comment?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be a generate-and-test loop:

```
do {
    distribute_balls_at_random();
} while (constraint_not_satisfied())
```

There are probably other approaches that are much more efficient, but this will be the easiest to code.

Comment: @smilingpoplar - If the process for distributing the balls randomly was sensitive to the number of balls already in each bucket (i.e., lower when the bucket had more balls), this might be sufficiently efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the `O(n)` algorithm with the `diff <= 1`:

- Shuffle the balls with the [Modern Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)
- Now use the simple division hashing `h(k) = k mod m` to distribute n balls to m buckets

The `diff` will be either 0, if `n mod m == 0`, or 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
function do(int n, int m, int diff){
      buckets = array of size m with initial values = 0
      while(n-- > 0){
          int limit = 1000;
          while(limit > 0){
              int idx = random number from 0 to m
              buckets[idx]+=1
              int min = min_element(buckets)
              int max = max_element(buckets)
              if(buckets[max] - buckets[min] <= diff) break
              buckets[idx]-=1
              limit--
          }
          if(limit == 0){
              int min = min_element(buckets)
              buckets[min]++;
              int max = max_element(buckets)
              if(buckets[max] - buckets[min) > diff)
                  return false; //there is no valid distribution
          }

      }
      print buckets
      return true
}
```

limit is a parameter you can adjust as you want. Greater values ensure more randomness and less values ensure better performance. You can try many test cases and come out with the best value suitable for you.

Comment: I think there is a space for many optimizations. for example instead of calling min_elemnt and max_element, they could be combined in one function and the calculated value for both is stored in 2 variables passed by reference. But this is the simplest version anyway